How to set freezeAuthority and mintAuthority to null?
I'm trying to mint a token along with metadata. Since Solana has moved to Metaplex for token metadata I've been trying to get it working.
Now that I have finally managed t o get it working I am having hard time figuring out where to define mintAuthority and freezeAuthority. I already tried setting authority option to null but it is not working. I would like to be able to set mintAuthority and freezeAuthority separately.
createAndMint(umi, {
    mint,
    authority: null,
    name: metadata.name,
    symbol: metadata.symbol,
    uri: metadata.uri,
    sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(0),
    decimals: 9,
    amount: 10**10,
    tokenOwner: null,
    tokenStandard: TokenStandard.Fungible,
    updateAuthority: null,
  }).sendAndConfirm(umi, {send: {skipPreflight: true, maxRetries: 2}})
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Successfully minted 1 billion tokens (", mint.publicKey, ")");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error("Error minting tokens:", err);
    });


CreateAndMint is a Metaplex helper that needs to create the required accounts and then mint the tokens. By default the freeze and mint authorities go to the umi.identity you initialized umi with.
It's not possible to revoke the mint and freeze authorities using the method.
It is possible however to compose of your mint ix together with the revoke instructions
import {
    clusterApiUrl,
    Connection,
    PublicKey,
    TransactionMessage,
    VersionedTransaction,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import {
    generateSigner,
    keypairIdentity,
    percentAmount,
    signTransaction,
 } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi";
import {
    fromWeb3JsTransaction,
    toWeb3JsInstruction,
    toWeb3JsTransaction,
} from "@metaplex-foundation/umi-web3js-adapters";
import { createUmi } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults";

import { createSetAuthorityInstruction } from "@solana/spl-token";

const conn = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));
const umi = createUmi(conn);

async function mintAndRevoke() {
    const mint = generateSigner(umi);

    // mint IX
    let mintIxs = await createAndMint(umi, {
        mint,
        name: metadata.name,
        symbol: metadata.symbol,
        uri: metadata.uri,
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(0),
        decimals: 9,
        amount: 10**10,
        isMutable: false,
        tokenStandard: TokenStandard.Fungible,
    }).getInstructions()[0];

    // revoke freeze auth
    let revokeFreezeAuthIx = createSetAuthorityInstruction(
        new PublicKey(mint.publicKey),
        new PublicKey(umi.identity.publicKey),
        AuthorityType.FreezeAccount,
        null
    );

    // revoke mint auth
    let revokeMintAuthIx = createSetAuthorityInstruction(
        new PublicKey(mint.publicKey),
        new PublicKey(umi.identity.publicKey),
        AuthorityType.MintTokens,
        null
    );

    // construct versioned tx msg
    const messageV0 = new TransactionMessage({
        payerKey: new PublicKey(umi.identity.publicKey),
        recentBlockhash: (await umi.rpc.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash,
        instructions: [
            toWeb3JsInstruction(mintIxs), // convert from umi ix
            revokeFreezeAuthIx,
            revokeMintAuthIx,
        ],
    }).compileToV0Message();

    const tx = new VersionedTransaction(messageV0);

    // sign with mint and auth
    let signedTx = await signTransaction(fromWeb3JsTransaction(tx), [
        mint,
        umi.identity,
    ]);

    // //convert to web3 js TX
    const web3JSTx = toWeb3JsTransaction(signedTx);

    let sig = await conn.sendTransaction(web3JSTx);
    console.log(`https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${sig}?cluster=devnet`);
}

mintAndRevoke().then().catch(console.error);

The two instruction bundled with the mint instruction revoke the freeze and mint respectively. It is possible to build separate transactions using the two and send them independently but sending 3 separate txs seems cumbersome
Revoke freeze auth
    let revokeFreezeAuthIx = createSetAuthorityInstruction(
        new PublicKey(mint.publicKey),
        new PublicKey(umi.identity.publicKey),
        AuthorityType.FreezeAccount,
        null
    );

Revoke mint auth
    let revokeMintAuthIx = createSetAuthorityInstruction(
        new PublicKey(mint.publicKey),
        new PublicKey(umi.identity.publicKey),
        AuthorityType.MintTokens,
        null
    );

